# Pegar dados que não estão na tabela

Tags: mysql

Em Mysql tenho uma tabela **login**, que mostra quem logou no sistema:

id | cod_usuario

Depois do site pronto e funcionando o cliente me passou uma lista de cod_usuario que PODEM logar no sistema, então criei uma tabela **pode** e fiz essa verificação sempre que alguém faz o login, quem não ta na **pode** não consegue logar, sem problemas.

Agora o cliente quer saber quem já logou anterioromente no sistema e que não estavava na tabela **pode**, como fazer essa verificação?

Seria algo do tipo:

```
SELECT cod FROM login
LEFT JOIN pode ON pode.cod_usuario = login.cod_usuario
```

Mas não sei como pegar os que estão na tabela **login** e NÃO estão na tabela **pode**

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se o retorno do `LEFT JOIN` é nulo:

```
SELECT cod FROM login
LEFT JOIN pode ON pode.cod_usuario = login.cod_usuario
WHERE pode.cod_usuario IS NULL;
```

Se for `NULL` não existe na tabela `pode`.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Usando uma subconsulta - tem a vantagem de ser mais óbvia para o leitor casual

```
SELECT cod FROM login WHERE cod_usuario NOT IN (SELECT cod_usuario FROM pode);
```

[image: login]

[image: pode]

[image: resultado]

2 - Usando `left join` - pode ser executada mais rapidamente que uma subconsulta e funciona em todas as versões do MySQL.

```
SELECT login.cod FROM login LEFT JOIN pode ON (login.cod_usuario = pode.cod_usuario) WHERE pode.cod_usuario IS NULL;
```

[image: alternativa]

Answer (score 0):

Outra possibilidade:

```
SELECT cod 
  FROM login
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM pode 
                    WHERE pode.cod_usuario = login.cod_usuario)
```